# Upside down on iPhone iOS 6?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, ios6, autorotate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Rotation behaving differently on iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536645/rotation-behaving-differently-on-ios6)

I want my app to support the upside down orientation on the iPhone. This works in iOS 5, but I'm having difficulty making it work on iOS 6.

Apple's documentation mentions that the default supported orientations are everything on iPad, and everything *except* upside down on iPhone. I want to support everything on both; I have personally run into situations where wires are in the way in standard portrait mode, and don't want to arbitrarily decide for my users that they can't use the app upside down if they have a similar problem.

Here's what I've done so far:

1. My view controller's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation;` return `YES` for all orientations, as required for iOS 5. (I have also tried commenting out this view controller's `shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:`, on the off chance that iOS 6 made decisions based on its presence. It did not help.)
2. My view controller's `supportedInterfaceOrientations` returns `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`.
3. My application delegate's `application:supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:` returns `UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll`.
4. All orientation modes are selected in the target's summary page.

What am I missing?

Comment: Look at solution explained there, basically it is fixed by subclassing the UINavigationController and making it the rootViewController of the main windows in your AppDelegate:

Rotation behaving differently on iOS6: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536645/rotation-behaving-differently-on-ios6/12540375#12540375

Comment: Thanks, iMathieuB. This is a dupe of that question. Closing.

Comment: Hmm. Apparently even as the question author, I need more votes to close. Feel free to add yours. :)

Comment: You can also flag for speedy closure... but you don't have to do that now :)