# ViewController not rotating on iOS6

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, rotation

The majority of my application does not support rotation. On the supported orientations, I only have portait selected. On the UIViewController subclass that the application uses I have this:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return NO;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    NSLog(@"supported?");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {

    NSLog(@"preferred");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

In the UIViewController subclass that does support orientation, I have this:

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate {
    return YES;
}

-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    NSLog(@"supported?");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

-(UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {

    NSLog(@"preferred");
    return UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait;
}
```

My application does not rotate on any view however, including this one. How can make it rotate here as I want it to?

Comment: Did you add all of the orientations to your supported orientations in your Info.plist?

Comment: No, I only have portait selected as a supported orientation. If i enable landscape it just rotates to landscape on every view controller.

Comment: Do you have a navigation controller?

Comment: Well you should support all the orientations that your app uses. So the question should be why your view controllers rotate to landscape.

Comment: @rooster117 Yes. DrummerB - Alright, so with it set to on, how do i stop it from rotating to landscape on certain views?

Comment: alright well I actually answered a similar question in Ravi's link below but your navigation controller is the key as the autorotation rules changed with ios6. I wrote about it here: http://www.roostersoftstudios.com/2012/09/21/ios6-autorotation-changes/

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a navigation controller, make sure you do this in your App Delegate:

`self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;`

For additional references, check this question from SO:

[Rotation behaving differently on iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536645/rotation-behaving-differently-on-ios6/12536787#12536787)

Comment: This should solve your problem.  I spent hours the other day trying to figure this out and was glad that in the end I was able to solve it with this line on my app delegate.