# App only rotates in iOS 6 and not in iOS 5

Tags: xcode, ios5, ios6, xcode4.5, autorotate

I have made an app targeted for iOS 5 and iOS 6, and for some reason it only rotates when using it on devices with iOS 6, wether on an iPhone or an iPad, and doesn't rotate on devices using iOS 5. My app is universal. Please help me resolve this problem! Thanks

Answer (score 8):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
{
    return ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));
}

- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortraitUpsideDown);
}
```

overide these two methods in your all uiviewcontroller subclasses ...... this will work for ios 6 and earlier

Comment: Note this example supports only two states: 'upright' (Portrait) and 'upside-down' (PortraitUpsideDown).

Answer (score 5):

iOS 5 and iOS 6 call different orientation and rotation delegates.  In iOS 5, implement:

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:, which is deprecated in iOS 6.

So, in iOS 6, make sure you set a root view controller, and implement:

shouldAutorotate:,  supportedInterfaceOrientations  and  supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. You can check the answer of this question:

[Rotation behaving differently on iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536645/rotation-behaving-differently-on-ios6/12540375#12540375)

To summarize, to have autorotation fully work in iOS 5 and iOS 6, and also handling PortraitUpsideDown orientation, I had to implement a custom UINavigationController and assign it to `self.window.rootViewController` in the app delegate `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method.

Answer (score 0):

shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is deprecated in ios6.

so if you wnat to run app on both os version then add shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation too as follows

```
//for ios6
 - (BOOL)shouldAutorotate {

        UIInterfaceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

        if (orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft  ||orientation ==  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ) 
{

            return YES;
        }
        return NO;
        }

//for ios5

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation {
    //interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight; 
    if (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft  ||interfaceOrientation ==  UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight ) {

        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

to support autorotations in both ios5 and ios6 we need to provide call backs in case of ios6....`[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

and we need to call

```
- (NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
```

}

```
-(BOOL)shouldAutoRotate{
    return YES;
  }
```

for ios5

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation
```

{
    return ((toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) || (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown));
}

Comment: hmm ... didn't I format the this already? No, it was another copy: So please done't post the exact same answer to multiple questions: it's either not a good fit for all or the questions are duplicates which should be flagged/closed as such.