# Orientation Issues in ios 6.0

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation, device-orientation

I have already completed my app in portrait orientation for iPhone and iPad, Now i need this same for the landscape orientation , I was used only xib's for both iPhone & iPad .and some UI are created in programatically. Just now i was Use this code:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    // return your mask here e.g.:
    if(UIDeviceOrientationIsPortrait([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation]))
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;
    else
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}
```

but it does not work properly, so can anyone help me......?

Comment: i hope this link will be helpful to you

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13100347/app-only-rotates-in-ios-6-and-not-in-ios-5/15240379#15240379

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this code to the following:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait | UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;  
}
```

And add the following:

```
- (BOOL) shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Thanq Sviatoslav, But here where i can check the conditions for example , if (UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait) else ....?Coz i might resizing the UI similar to the orientation.

Answer (score 0):

Finally i done that , now am using this code;

-(void) willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration {
     if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft) {
      //  NSLog(@"Landscape left");

```
} else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight) {
    NSLog(@"Landscape right");

} else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait) {
  //  NSLog(@"Portrait");

} else if (toInterfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {
   // NSLog(@"Upside down");
}
```

}
 It was working good for all orientation , Thanq all.