# iAD bottom view when change orientation

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, iad, device-orientation

Currently I use this to code for loading the iAD banners.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    adView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
    CGRect adFrame = adView.frame;
    adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height;
    adView.frame = adFrame;

    [adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth];

    [self.view addSubview:adView];
    adView.delegate=self;

    self.bannerIsVisible=NO;

}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    if (!self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];

        CGRect adFrame = adView.frame;
        adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-adView.frame.size.height;
        adView.frame = adFrame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = YES;
    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    if (self.bannerIsVisible)
    {
        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

        CGRect adFrame = adView.frame;
        adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height+adView.frame.size.height;
        adView.frame = adFrame;

        [UIView commitAnimations];
        self.bannerIsVisible = NO;
    }
}
```

The problem is that I want to auto set the iAD view to the bottom of the view also when the device orientation changes. I tried lots of things but none of thim are working.

Also why do I have to use notification center to check device orientations? `DidRotateToInterfaceOrientation` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: in iOS 6 there were changes to rotation behavior, see here for example  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536645/rotation-behaving-differently-on-ios6 . When interface rotates, set adbanner frame again.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I may have understood this wrong, but if you set the following:

```
[adView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];
```

This should mean that as your view gets bigger/smaller (as you rotate) it should increase/decrease the 'top' margin, therefore should stick to the bottom.

I may have understood this incorrectly though.. are you able to provide screenshots of what is currently happening if the above idea doesn't work?

Answer (score 0):

Try this in your `viewDidLoad` method:

```
CGRect adFrame = adView.frame;
adFrame.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.height-adView.frame.size.height;
adView.frame = adFrame;
```

It will set your iAd to the bottom of your view irrespective of the device type. Don't set the frame of iAd in the delegate method.

Comment: I have that in bannerViewDidLoadAd.

Comment: Edited my answer. Please check again.

Comment: That doesn't seem to make any different.

Answer (score 0):

This solution is for iOS 6

Use notifications to listen for a device orientation change in the viewDidLoad method of your view controller:

```
UIDevice *device = [UIDevice currentDevice];
[device beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];
NSNotificationCenter *nc = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];
[nc addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:device];

UIInterfaceOrientation destOrientation = self.interfaceOrientation;
```

Then use an if statement in your viewController to listen for the change, and reposition the Ad Banner View when the orientation changes:

```
if (destOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait || destOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown) {

    ADBannerView *bannerView = (ADBannerView *)[self.view viewWithTag:615];
    CGRect myAdBanner = bnrAd.frame;
    myAdBanner.origin.x = 0;
    myAdBanner.origin.y = 410;
    bannerView.frame = myAdBanner;

} else {

    ADBannerView *bannerView = (ADBannerView *)[self.view viewWithTag:615];
    CGRect myAdBanner = bnrAd.frame;
    myAdBanner.origin.x = 0;
    myAdBanner.origin.y = 265;
    bannerView.frame = myAdBanner;
}
```

Don't forget to call the methods to load the ad into your view:

```
- (void) bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner {
    bnrAd = _bannerView;
}

- (BOOL) bannerViewActionShouldBegin:(ADBannerView *)banner willLeaveApplication:(BOOL)willLeave {
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

see the code below and I am using this code in my iPad App that need to support iOS 6 and above:

**in your .h file**

```
#import <iAd/iAd.h>

@interface MyViewController : UIViewController <ADBannerViewDelegate> {

    ADBannerView *bannerView;

    BOOL bannerIsVisible;

}
```

**in your .m file**

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // detect device orientation change
    [[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) {

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter]
         addObserver:self selector:@selector(orientationChanged:)
         name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification
         object:[UIDevice currentDevice]];

    }

    [self showiAds];

}

- (void) showiAds{

    bannerView = [[ADBannerView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"7.0")) {

        UIDeviceOrientation orientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

        if(orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft || orientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) {

            [bannerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];

        } else {

            [bannerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleTopMargin];

        }

    }

    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"7.0")) {

        [bannerView setAutoresizingMask:UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth |UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleBottomMargin];

    }

    bannerView.delegate = self;

    bannerView.hidden = YES;

    [self.view addSubview:bannerView];

    bannerIsVisible = NO;

}

- (void)bannerViewDidLoadAd:(ADBannerView *)banner
{
    NSLog(@"bannerViewDidLoadAd");

    if (!bannerIsVisible) {

        bannerView.hidden = NO;

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOn" context:NULL];

        // banner is invisible now and moved out of the screen on 50 px
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, self.view.frame.size.height - bannerView.frame.size.height);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        bannerIsVisible = YES;

    }
}

- (void)bannerView:(ADBannerView *)banner didFailToReceiveAdWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"didFailToReceiveAdWithError : %@", [error localizedDescription]);

    if (bannerIsVisible) {

        [UIView beginAnimations:@"animateAdBannerOff" context:NULL];

        // Assumes the banner view is placed at the bottom of the screen.
        banner.frame = CGRectOffset(banner.frame, 0, banner.frame.size.height);

        [UIView commitAnimations];

        bannerIsVisible = NO;

    }

}
```

Hope you understand above code. Good luck

Cheerio,
Mark Thien