# How can Upside Down orientation be continually detected on an iPhone in viewWillTransitionToSize:coordinator: on iOS 9?

Tags: ios, swift, ios9, uiinterfaceorientation

I’m handling rotation changes in `viewWillTransitionToSize:coordinator:` on an iPhone with iOS 9.1 and I’m able to successfully detect **Upside Down** orientation if the device is turned upside down, from right side up, *after starting the app for the first time.* **Further rotations to Upside Down do not result in further detections of the Upside Down orientation.**

I’m using the following code in a view controller:

```
override func viewWillTransitionToSize(size: CGSize, 
                                       withTransitionCoordinator coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransitionToSize(size, withTransitionCoordinator: coordinator)
```

I have all orientations checked off in the General tab of the Xcode project.

I followed the suggestion in the accepted answer for [Rotation behaving differently on iOS6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12536645/rotation-behaving-differently-on-ios6) and implemented my own custom navigation controller.

```
class MyNavigationController: UINavigationController {
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }    
}
```

That did not result in successful continual detection of Upside Down in `viewWillTransitionToSize:coordinator:`.

Adding the same methods to my view controller also did not change the results:

```
class MyViewController: UIViewController {
    override func shouldAutorotate() -> Bool {
        return true
    }

    override func supportedInterfaceOrientations() -> UIInterfaceOrientationMask {
        return UIInterfaceOrientationMask.All
    }
```

Setting up a separate observer using

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "deviceOrientationDidChange:", name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification, object: nil)
UIDevice.currentDevice().beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications()
```

also does not continually report the Upside Down orientation when I check the bounds with:

```
UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds
```

Instead, the bounds are reported as being the same as for landscape.

Ideally, I would like to have Upside Down be handled by `viewWillTransitionToSize:coordinator:` but I’m open to workarounds, too.